# How to access remote connection requests from safari, facebook and other applications on iPhone

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios4, service

I noticed one application on app store recently named onavo which access internet connection usage from other applications on iPhone like safari, facebook, youtube, etc. Is there any API available for this. How they have implemented it. Curious to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer on Quora. As follow:

### http://www.quora.com/How-is-Onavo-able-to-direct-all-the-data-traffic-to-their-proxy-without-using-iOS-private-APIs

Roi Tiger, CTO of Onavo

Hi, I'm the CTO of Onavo, thank you for checking out our service. After installing Onavo you are prompted to install a configuration profile which allows the data to be redirected through Onavo's servers using a proxy server settings.

Configuration profile installation does not require any private API access in the iOS platform.

Another answer:
http://www.quora.com/How-does-Onavo-manage-to-compress-data-traffic

Answer (score 2):

They're not monitoring the apps’ data usage on the phone itself. It looks like Onavo sets up a proxy on the phone (probably via a configuration profile) so that your data traffic goes through their servers, so monitoring which sites that traffic is going through is trivial on their end. From their [privacy policy](http://www.onavo.com/privacy_policy) (emphasis mine):

> Onavo provides services for reducing data usage of certain mobile phones. To benefit from the Services, your access to the Internet through your mobile phone will be **routed through Onavo's servers**, which strive to reduce the volume of your downloads, and potentially your uploads as well.

Comment: Noah, Thanks for the response. But i could not find an API for setting the proxy even.